# inline_keyboard php Telegram

Tags: php, botón, telegram, bot

estoy desarrollando un bot de Telegram en php y estoy teniendo una dificultad con las CallbackQuery de los botones en línea.

Este es el código que utilizo para enviar el mensaje en el que va el botón en línea. Esto funciona bien

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class TelegramController extends Controller
{
    private $urlBot;
    private $updates;
    private $chat_id;

    /**
     * Create a new TelegramController instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct($updates)
    {   $bot = env('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN');
        $this->urlBot = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{$bot}";
        $this->updates = $updates;
        $this->chat_id = $updates['message']['from']['id'];
    }

    public function callback(){

        if(isset($this->updates['callback_data'])){
            \Log::build([
                'driver' => 'single',
                'path' => storage_path('logs/call.log'),
            ])->info($this->updates['callback_data']);
        }


    }

    /**
     * Handle the /start command.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function start()
    {  
        $keyboard_la_quiero = json_encode([
            "inline_keyboard" => [
                [
                    [
                        "text" => "\xF0\x9F\x9A\x95 La Quiero",
                        "callback_data" => "yo|1" //.$viaje_id
                    ]
                ]    
            ]
        ]);

        $data = http_build_query([
            'text' => "Informacion de la carrera",
            'chat_id' => $this->chat_id,
            'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
            'reply_markup' => $keyboard_la_quiero
        ]);

        $r = Http::get($this->urlBot."/sendMessage", $data);
           
    }

    
}
```

[image: Así se queda cargando al presionar el botón]

Este es el código que se ejecuta al recibir información. También funciona correctamente. Pero no le llega nada de callback_query ni ninguna otra cosa al presionar un botón.

```
    
    if (isset($updates['callback_query'])) {
        $telegram->callback();
    }else{
        $telegram->start();
    }
```

Puede alguien ayudarme a descubrir el porque. Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: y que dice la documentacion???

Comment: En la documentación no he podido encontrar nada al respecto. Porque el problema es que al pulsar el botón no envía nada hacia el Webhook.

Comment: bueno hay muy poca informacion/codigopara poder darte una ayuda.... a simple vista pareciera que $this->urlBot no esta declarado... pero sepa que hay detras .... en codigo que no has compartido...

Comment: Edite la publicación y puse todo el código del controlador